# cropper doesn't load in img element in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, crop, cropperjs

I'm using fengyuanchen's cropper to crop an uploaded image and then post it to form.

```
<div id="change-dp" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-outside" type="button" uk-close></button>
            <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Change Profile Picture</h2><br>
            <form action="{{url_for('upload_dp', username=username)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" placeholder="Upload profile picture" onchange="loadFile(event)" id="uploaded" required>
            <img id="dp" onchange=""/>
                    
            <div id="cropped"></div>

            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var cropper;

function loadFile(image) {
    var dp = document.getElementById('dp')
    dp.src = URL.createObjectURL(image.target.files[0]);
    dp.onload = function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(dp.src)};
    cropper = new Cropper(dp, { aspectRatio: 1 });
};
```

The idea is that once the user uploads an image, it is rendered with a cropper, on submit, I'll generate cropped data into cropped div with js and submit that as a dp to server. I'm unable to get a display of cropper.

I do not use jquery in which most documentation is.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trhx6om8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you load cropper script untrusted domain site & forgot to load the css file as well. Here is the official CDN link: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/cropperjs

```
// CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.7/cropper.css" integrity="sha512-AuLN6bHjJzqZ+Iw48+GdQPp5uKBdPX6+zWV37ju9zw7XIrevIX01RsLtpTU/zCoQcKrQRPe/EpwDpZiv7OUYMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

// Script
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.7/cropper.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4T9zTrqZUWCEhVU2uD0m47ADCWYRfEGNQ+dx/lYdQvOn+5FJZxcyHOY68QKsjTEC7Oa234qhXFhjPGQu6vhqg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. I use downloaded files. This is just a setup for jsfiddle. I don't think security is a concern on jsfiddle.

Comment: It is unimportant. Cropper doesn't show up. Do you know what's the problem in the above code?

Comment: How can I say if I don't see how you implemented?  But likely your Cropper object/styles weren't loaded, the style is also important which displays something for you to interact with?

Comment: There's no problem with loading cropper.min.css or cropper.min.js, that I can assure you. Above code gets rendered on jsfiddle. You can use your cdnjs links if you want to on the above jsfiddle, it won't make a difference. I've written the code above.

Comment: I did try your above code which is working fine. Anyway I can't help unless I know more about how you implemented :)

Comment: Send me your jsfiddle link. Every bit of my implementation is given above except loading css and js files which is absolutely trivial.

Comment: I used your link above except for replacing the trusted domain for script/css files

Comment: That's correct. It did work. I think cropper.min.css doesn't work. cropper.css gave me the cropper. Thanks a lot man @tmhao2005